# How can I change wluser's password after installed IBM worklight?

Tags: db2, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I change wluser's password?
I changed it's password, and "wl.db.password" of worklight.properties.
But both worklight console and application center didn't work.
After that ,I took back the password, then both of them work correctly.
Has anyone tried that?
※「wluser」 is db2user for worklight.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_creating_the_db2_databases.html?resultof=%22%64%62%32%22%20%22%77%6c%75%73%65%72%22%20

My Environment is below.
Windows 7
Worklight V5.0.5.1
WAS V8.5
DB2 V9.7

When I changed wluser's password, I got following errors.

Worklight console

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Project not initialized

applicationcenter,

> An unexpected error occurred (HTTP Status 500)

Comment: To be clear - you say you have changed the username and password in worklight.properties, ok, but have you also changed these values in the database settings, as well as re-deployed the .war file?

Comment: Thanks,Idan.First I changed wluser's windows password.Second,I have changed worklight properties, and re-deploy the .warfile.That's all.I didn't change any DB2 settings.Because I think DB2 use OS authentiction...Should I change any databbase settings?

Comment: What is "wluser's windows password"? There is a schema in DB2 and this schema has a username and password, you'll need to change those as well I suspect...

Comment: Thanks Again,Idan. I think db2 schema doesn't have password. [http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/db2-l/db2-password-change-738477] [http://www.dbforums.com/db2/998756-how-change-password-udb-db2.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a worklight.properties, you have the option to specify the database connection parameters through two means, described in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_ibm_worklight_database_setup.html. In order to be able to modify the password from the application server console, rather than in the worklight.properties file, you need to use the "JNDI way" of setting the database connection properties, as documented in http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Ft_transporting_the_app.html.

In WebSphere Application Server, you find the location to edit the DB2 password by opening the WAS administration console, then opening the "Security > Global security" page, then clicking on the "Java Authentication and Authorization Service > J2C authentication data", in the resulting list pick the "WorklightDb2DatabaseCredentials" credentials and edit them. Note that for other types of databases than DB2, the password is stored as a custom property of the datasource, rather than as JAAS authentication data.

In WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile, the password is in the server.xml file of the server, in the <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/WorklightDS"> and <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"> elements. Simply edit this file; Liberty will notice that it's been edited and reload it.

In Tomcat, the password is in the conf/server.xml file. Here, the password is in the <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightDS"> and <Resource name="jdbc/WorklightReportsDS"> elements. Simply edit this file, then restart the Tomcat server.